# Correct way to use Facebook Like plugin in Django

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-like, xfbml, facebook-social-plugins

I am using the following Facebook code to show the Like plugin when iterating through my list of Post objects.

```
<fb:like href="{% url post post.id %}" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450" font=""></fb:like>
```

The resulting HTML is as such:

```
 <fb:like href="/9/" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450" font=""></fb:like>
```

However, when I click the Like button, my FB profile says that I Liked `www.facebook.com/9/` instead of my own domain name.

What did I do wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `{% url post post.id %}` returns an absolute url path without the domain. Facebook plugins need the full url with host. To make your page likable you also need to pass your domain somehow to the template. Lets assume you createa template variable `host` via `request.get_host()` in your views and pass it to your template then the url statement could look like this:

```
<fb:like href="http://{{host}}{% url post post.id %}" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450" font=""></fb:like>
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured. Kinda weird. I thought FB's code would be smarter than that. Luckily Django's template tag has the `request.get_host` method. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently this is the same for all other similar API's, like the Tweet-Button or other share buttons. Just keep it in mind for the future.